Sequential updating vs Marginalized updating
Suppose I need to sample a posterior $\pi(\theta|D)$, whose analytic form is not tractable (not even up to a normalizing constant). However, I somehow manage to obtain an augmented posterior $\pi(\theta,z|D)$.
My question is: if I do a sequential (Gibbs) update as follows:

Update $z\leftarrow z'$ using $z'\sim\pi(z|\theta,D)$;

Update $\theta\leftarrow\theta'$ using $\theta'\sim\pi(\theta|z',D)$;

Loop


Then if I discard those samples of $z$ and only keep those of $\theta$, are these samples of $\theta$ equivalent to samples from $\pi(\theta|D):=\int\pi(\theta,z|D){\rm d}z$? Thanks!
Note that I'm talking about equivalence in the context that 2 compared samples converge at the same rate for analysis. Also, the "update" may not be directly sampling from the distribution, but using some MCMC method (e.g. Langevin dynamics).


are these samples of $$ equivalent to samples from $\pi(|)$?

This part of the question already has some answers on Cross Validated, see eg this entry.
By definition of the marginal distribution density
$$\pi_1(\theta|D):=\int_\mathcal Z\pi_2(\theta,z|D)\,{\rm d}z$$
$\pi_1(\cdot)$ is the density of $Z$ when the pair $(\theta,Z)$ has a joint distribution with density $\pi_2(\cdot)$. This validation applies to a wide set of simulation algorithms that use auxiliary variables, beyond Gibbs sampling.
While this may sound paradoxical, when producing a realisation $z$ of $Z\sim\pi_3(z|\theta,D)$, this realisation is both a realisation from $\pi_3(z|\theta,D)$ and from
$$\pi_4(z|D):=\int_\Theta\pi_2(\theta,z|D)\,{\rm d}\theta$$
(when the chain is in its stationary regime).

equivalence in the context that 2 compared samples converge at the same rate

This part of the question has no answer since it does not describe which simulation method would be used for the direct simulation from $\pi_1(\theta|D)$

the "update" may not be directly sampling from the distribution, but using some MCMC method

Replacing direct simulation from the conditional $\pi_3(z|\theta,D)$ with one step of an MCMC algorithm target $\pi_3(\cdot|\theta,D)$ as in Metropolis-within-Gibbs does not impact the validity of the simulation, even though it may slow down convergence or/and exploration of the target support.
